# iOS iBeacon, issues ranging mulitple beacons

Tags: ios, location, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I've  got a strange one. I have a simple iBeacon app setup with the standard  methods for entering and exiting regions, initializing a beacon region,  and beacon ranging. I've also got a couple of iBeacons placed around the  room. Everything works perfectly when there is only one beacon in the  room, when I move away the ranging method says I am 'proximity.far',  when I move closer it says that I am 'proximity.near' and when I put the  device right next to the iBeacon it tells me that I am  'proximity.immediate'. Thats great! But the problem I am having is when I  add another beacon to the mix. when there is two beacons in the room  the app enters into the beacon region for the beacons with the  particular UUID, both beacons use the same UUID, beacon one is using a  major:minor of 1:1 and beacon two is using 1:3, i think their  identifiers are different but im sure that makes no difference? So when  only one beacon is in the room the ranging works perfectly, but when the  two beacons are in the room the proximity in the ranging method only  shows 'far'. This is strange considering that when I come near to beacon  one the app picks up the major and

minor numbers of beacon one,  and when I move near to beacon two the app picks up the major and minor  numbers of beacon two, through out the movements between these beacons  the proximity remains 'far'.

This  is confusing! My only thoughts on the reason for this happening is that  because I am close to one beacon I am far from the other, so no matter  how close I am to one beacon I am always 'proximity.far' from another!  But how is it staying in far when the app detects the major and minor  numbers of the beacon I am close to? I'm guessing that if I move the  beacons far enough apart so that they are not within each others regions  ranging will work properly, but for what I am making this app for I  need the beacons to be within a couple of meters of each other.

Any insight into this problem will be met with curtious bows.

Thank you!

Comment: I would be curious if you get the same results with a different app, perhaps try our Locate Beacon app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8

Comment: Can you post your code that displays the proximity field of each beacon?  Can you also display the accuracy field of each beacon and see if it looks correct?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved, turns out i was under the idea that the 'last object' in the beacon array that gets passed into ranging method is the nearest beacon, turns out i (or whatever tutorial i picked it up from!) was wrong, i used a for in loop to loop through the beacon array and pick out the nearest one.

Thanks!